# is it possible that in a created pdf document, allows to users add text, add checkboxes and remove images to customize the PDF form?

Tags: pdf

I have create a html form that allows user response several questions, the html file is send to user, it open on a browser and  is filled.  But futhermore the user can add new sections of questions, add questions with its related checkboxes, delete section and questions, and delete initial images.  I allow this interacttion with javascript and is working ok.   But i want and i need achieve this functionality in a PDF document is that possible? what tecnology i must use? thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: Thank you KJ for your comment!!!  if i don't use JS but other secure and accepted language?

Comment: Thank you very much KJ, i going to read what you say!